# Problema con login php

Tags: php, sql, pdo

No estoy pudiendo validar el login. Es simplemente un ejercicio igual

```
    <?php
    $cons_usuario = "root";
    $cons_contra = "";
    $cons_base_datos = "test"; //nombrde de cada uno
    $cons_equipo = "localhost:3308";

    $obj_conexion = mysqli_connect($cons_equipo,$cons_usuario,$cons_contra,$cons_base_datos);

    if (!$obj_conexion){
        echo "<h3>No se ha podido conectar PHP - MySQL, verifique sus datos.</h3><hr><br>";
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['user']) && (isset($_REQUEST['pass']))) {
        $pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
        $user = $_REQUEST['user'];
        /* $token = md5($pass); */

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '$user' AND password = '$pass'";

        $select = (mysqli_query($obj_conexion, $sql) or die ("Problemas en el query".mysqli_error($obj_conexion)));
}
```

Este es mi codigo php

Me esta tirando error en la linea 22

Comment: Y cuál es el mensaje de error?

Comment: Y cuál es la linea 22?

Comment: El error que tira es que espera un resultado booleano. la linea 22 es la ultima linea. La conexion con sql, el $select, pude hacerla funcionar pero no logro hacer la validacion.

Comment: Te recomendaría que evites el uso de `die`, y que lo sustituyas por un control estricto en tu código. Asignar una variable con `or die(...)` no tiene mucho sentido, ni siquiera permite entender qué tiene que pasar en caso de algún fallo o error. En el código tampoco se ve que hagas nada con un eventual resultado de la consulta. Otro fallo es que tienes un `if` que evalúa la conexión y a continuación tienes código que seguirá ejecutándose haya conexión o no. Si no hay conexión, la parte del `isset` no debería ejecutarse. Falta dar coherencia estricta al código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomendaría que evites el uso de `die`, y que lo sustituyas por un control estricto en tu código. Asignar una variable con `or die(...)` no tiene mucho sentido, ni siquiera permite entender qué tiene que pasar en caso de algún fallo o error.

En el código tampoco se ve que hagas nada con un eventual resultado de la consulta.

Otro fallo es que tienes un `if` que evalúa la conexión y a continuación tienes código que seguirá ejecutándose haya conexión o no. Si no hay conexión, la parte del `isset` no debería ejecutarse.

Falta dar coherencia estricta al código. Esto es muy simple de hacer. Por *coherencia estricta*  entiendo que se controlen todas las eventualidades del código y al final se informe de lo que haya pasado. Aquí lo haremos sustituyendo los horribles `die()`por una variable `$msg` que recoja las salidas, sean de éxito o de error y al final imprimimos esa variable.

```
<?php
    $cons_usuario = "root";
    $cons_contra = "";
    $cons_base_datos = "test"; 
    $cons_equipo = "localhost:3308";
    $obj_conexion = mysqli_connect($cons_equipo,$cons_usuario,$cons_contra,$cons_base_datos);
    if (!$obj_conexion){
        $msg="<h3>No se ha podido conectar PHP - MySQL, verifique sus datos.</h3><hr><br>";
    } else {
        $user=!empty($_REQUEST['user']) ? $_REQUEST['user'] : NULL;
        $pass=!empty($_REQUEST['pass']) ? $_REQUEST['pass'] : NULL;
        if ($user && $pass) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '$user' AND password = '$pass'";
            if ($select = mysqli_query($obj_conexion, $sql)) {
                $msg="Hay datos... leer los datos";
            } else {
                $msg="Problemas en el query: ".mysqli_error($obj_conexion);
            }
        } else {
            $msg="Falta usuario y/o pass";
        }
    }
    echo $msg;
```

Sobre el uso de `die()` te dejo [este comentario de Hayley Watson en las Notas de contribución del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.die.php#109834), para comprender mejor por qué no deberías usarlo:

> Es un mal diseño confiar en `die()` para el manejo de errores en un
>   sitio web porque da como resultado una experiencia fea para los
>   usuarios del sitio: una página rota y, si tienen suerte, un mensaje de
>   error que no les sirve de nada . En lo que a ellos respecta, cuando la
>   página se rompe, todo el sitio también podría estar roto.
>
> Si alguna vez desea que el público use su sitio, siempre debe
>   diseñarlo para manejar los errores de una manera que les permita
>   continuar usándolo si es posible. Si no es posible y el sitio
>   realmente no funciona, asegúrese de averiguarlo para poder
>   solucionarlo. `die()` por sí solo tampoco lo hará.
>
> Si un congelador de supermercado se descompone, un cliente que quería
>   comprar un helado no espera ser expulsado del edificio.

Comment: Mil gracias, me ayudo bastante. Aun estoy en la etapa de aprendizaje. Y como haria para cotejarlo con la base de datos? Ya que tampoco me salia.

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido @DenisHugoPerafan. No entiendo qué quieres decir con *cotejarlo con la base de datos* ¿Podrías explicarlo mejor?

Comment: Poder chequear que los datos ingresados sean iguales a la base de datos. Si es igual entonces avanza a la siguiente pagina, sino que salte error.

Comment: @DenisHugoPerafan Eso depende, tratándose de verificaciones con passwords, primero hay que saber si cuando se crearon los usuarios y pusieron sus claves no usaste un `hash` para guardar las claves. Si ha sido así, entonces tienes que usar una función especifica para hacer la verificación. En cambio, si la clave se guardó tal cual (como una cadena más... lo cual no es recomendable) entonces podrías hacer un `SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM users WHERE user_name = '$user' AND password = '$pass'` y verificar si la consulta arroja un valor superior a `1`, lo cual indicaría que ese usuario existe.

Comment: lo que hice fue que la clave pase por un token y luego ese token se guarde