# Evitar INSERT al recargar la página

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Cuando el usuario le de a un <kbd>Botón</kbd> (luego de rellenar unos campos previos) este le permita insertar información en mi base de datos (luego de validar que todos los campos estén correctos).

El problema radica cuando el usuario recarga la página, ya que vuelve a insertar otra vez la misma información ya almacenada. Y así, n veces cada vez que el usuario recargue.

¿Existe alguna manera de poder evitar que el usuario inserte en la base de datos cada vez que recargue la página?

- Código en `PHP`:

```
public static function insertMarcajeModel($datosModel)
    {
        $canal = $datosModel['canal'];
        $aliado = $datosModel['aliado'];
        $gerente = $datosModel['gerente'];
        $cuentas = $datosModel['cuentas'];
        $error = 0;

        if( ($canal == 3 || $canal == 4) && is_null($aliado) && is_null($gerente) )
        {
            foreach($cuentas as $row)
            {
                $cuenta = (double) $row;

                //Codigo de los numeros de cuenta
                $stmt = Source::Conectar()->prepare("select G300CTA as Cuenta, G300CLI as Codigo, G300NCTL as Nombre from GSCF300 where G300CTA = ?"); 

                if ( $stmt && $stmt->execute( array($cuenta) ) ) 
                {
                    $resultado = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    $clientes[] = $resultado;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Error en la consulta SQL";
                }    
            }

            for($i = 0; $i < count($cuentas); $i++){
                $informacionCliente[$i] = array(
                    "numCuenta" => (int) $clientes[$i]['CUENTA'],
                    "nombre" => $clientes[$i]['NOMBRE'],
                    "codigo" => $clientes[$i]['CODIGO'],
                    "canal" => $canal,
                    "aliado" => $aliado,
                    "gerente" => $gerente
                );

                $stmt = Source::Conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO MARCAJE (CLIENTE,CUENTA,CODIGO,ID_CANAL,ID_GERENTE,ID_ALIADO)
                                                    VALUES (:nombre, :cuenta, :codigo, :canal, :gerente, :aliado)");

                $stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $informacionCliente[$i]['nombre']);
                $stmt->bindParam(":cuenta", $informacionCliente[$i]['numCuenta']);
                $stmt->bindParam(":codigo", $informacionCliente[$i]['codigo']);
                $stmt->bindParam(":canal", $informacionCliente[$i]['canal']);
                $stmt->bindParam(":gerente", $informacionCliente[$i]['gerente']);
                $stmt->bindParam(":aliado", $informacionCliente[$i]['aliado']);

                if( !$stmt->execute() ){
                    $error++;
                }

                if($error > 0){
                    return $errores = array(
                        "error" => $stmt->errorInfo(),
                        "bool" => false
                    );
                }

                $stmt->closeCursor();
            }

            if($error == 0){
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Puede que el contenido de [esta publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/290520/como-evitar-el-error-al-volver-a-la-p%c3%a1gina-anterior-despu%c3%a9s-de-un-submit) te sirva. En tu caso deberías redirigir a la misma página.

Comment: @Marcos muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo la respuesta de [@Marcos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16597/marcos), mediante el [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/290520/como-evitar-el-error-al-volver-a-la-p%c3%a1gina-anterior-despu%c3%a9s-de-un-submit) que recomendó, la solución fue implementar:

```php
header("Location: ...");
die();
```

- El código final quedo de la siguiente manera:

```php
public static function insertMarcajeModel($datosModel)
{
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        if($error == 0){
            //redirigir a la misma dirección del formulario
            header("Location: marcaje");
            die();
        }

}
```

Comment: De todos modos, no es recomendable usar `die()`, su presencia en el código (aunque el Manual de PHP lo usa en algunos ejemplos), son presagio de un mal diseño, de un código sobre el cual no tienes pleno control. Al final de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/324309/29967) yo traduje una nota del Manual de PHP ampliamente aceptada con algunos motivos contundentes para evitarlo. En tu caso podríamos afirmar sin riesgo a equivocarnos que estamos ante un mal diseño. ¿Por qué? Porque puedes usar Ajax para esto, evitando así redirecciones y ganando en experiencia del usuario (UX).