# Nosé el porque no me elimina el bono correspondiente en PHP PDO y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Cordial Saludo para todos, mi nombre es Iván Pacheco, y estoy realizando este proyecto, el cual es de agregar, modificar y eliminar los bonos correspondientes, pero no me está eliminando los bonos, a continuación, este es el siguiente código, mil gracias.

Código PHP

case "btnEliminar":

```
    try
    {
        $sentencia="DELETE Bon.id, Pref.id_prefijo FROM bonos Bon LEFT JOIN prefijo Pref ON Bon.id = pref.id_bono"; 
        $resultado=$pdo->prepare($sentencia);
        $resultado->execute(array(':id' => '$txtid'));
        echo "Persona Eliminada";
        $resultado->closeCursor();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die('Error : '.$e->getMessage());
    }
```

y este es la base de datos, les agradezco mucho

el cual se llama la tabla bonos, en el cual, tienen: id, serie2, serie3, fechabono.

En la parte del código PHP, al ejecutarlo, al intentar eliminar un bono me imprime Persona Eliminada, pero no me elimina el bono, se los agradezco mucho.

Answer (score 0):

¡Menos mal que no ha funcionado! De haberlo hecho, suponiendo que la consulta es correcta en todo, te habría borrado todos los registros que cumpliesen la condición del `JOIN` lo cual habría sido una catástrofe si no tuvieras un backup.

Por esta línea `$resultado->execute(array(':id' => '$txtid'));` se puede comprender que necesitas borrar los registros que tengan `id` igual a `$txtid`.  Entonces, eso tiene que ser especificado en la consulta SQL mediante un `WHERE`, lo cual no estás haciendo.

Debes cuidar también los *alias*  que das a tus tablas/columnas. Aunque a veces funciona, muchas veces los nombres son *case sensitive*, lo que significa que `Pref` puede no ser igual a `pref`. También, una práctica recomendada en ese sentido es usar *alias* cortos, de una o dos letras. No tiene sentido usar un *alias* casi del tamaño del nombre original.

La sentencia correcta sería así (ver el  `WHERE` de la última línea):

```
DELETE b.id, p.id_prefijo 
FROM bonos b 
    LEFT JOIN prefijo p ON b.id = p.id_bono 
WHERE b.id=:id;
```

Me he permitido usar los alias `b` y `p` para cada tabla. Faltaba también poner el *alias*  de tabla a la columna `id`.

Entonces, el código debería quedar así:

```
try
{
    $sentencia="DELETE b.id, p.id_prefijo FROM bonos b LEFT JOIN prefijo p ON b.id = p.id_bono WHERE b.id=:id"; 
    $resultado=$pdo->prepare($sentencia);
    $resultado->execute(array(':id' => $txtid));
    echo "Persona Eliminada";
    $resultado->closeCursor();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    die('Error : '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

## Algunas recomendaciones

- Evita el uso de `die`. Es considerado hoy día una mala práctica ([ver esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/324309/29967)), por más que el Manual de PHP insista en usar ejemplos basados en `die`. Esta función no te permite tener un control estricto de tu código en muchos contextos.
- Evita mostrar mensajes internos de la base de datos, mejor muestra mensajes personalizados. Por ejemplo PDO en algunos casos muestra hasta la contraseña de conexión cuando algo falla.
- En el array que pasas a `execute` no tienes necesidad de poner las variables entre comillas.
- Si tu base de datos está en el engine `InnoDB` lo que intentas hacer aquí podría manejarse mediante una restricción del integridad referencial del tipo `ON DELETE CASCADE`, para más detalles sobre esto puedes ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/105921/29967).

Comment: muchas gracias A.Cedaño por ayudarme, si señor, tienes toda la razón el problema es que hasta ahorita volví a retomar sobre tema de PHP, HTML5 CSS3, Ajax, entre otras de construir sitios web y pues hace mucho tiempo que no me había actualizado, nuevamente muchísimas gracias, voy hacer los cambios correspondientes. Ya en una o dos horas te estaré comentando del resultado

Comment: @IvanPacheco revisa de nuevo la respuesta y el código, puede que haya más errores, por ejemplo la forma de usar los alias de las tablas no era uniforme y faltaba poner al alias a la columna `id` .